# I can't format date from SugarJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I've tried using new module for my project, SugarJS. I can print the date, but can't format it. Here is my code

```
const Sugar = require('sugar')

let yesterday = Sugar.Date.create()
let yesterdayWithFormat = Sugar.Date.create().format("{dd}")
```

yesterday output is `2019-10-14T06:52:28.466Z` but yesterdayWithFormat error `Sugar.Date.create(...).format is not a function`

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `format` functions you need to call `Sugar.extend();`:

```
const Sugar = require('sugar')

Sugar.extend();

let yesterday = Sugar.Date.create()
let yesterdayWithFormat = Sugar.Date.create().format("{dd}")

console.log(yesterday)
console.log(yesterdayWithFormat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `extend` is optional as the same can be done with `default` setup. 
Try this

```
const Sugar = require('sugar')

let yesterday = Sugar.Date.create()
let yesterdayWithFormat = Sugar.Date.format(yesterday, '{dd}');
```

You are trying to extend `format` from `create` which seems to be not available.